# Magento return 404 on every page including admin

Tags: magento-1.9, database, 404-page

Our store returns a 404 error on every possible request.
I've tried cleaning cache, indexes, redis, etc.. But no success. (NB Cache was already turned off)
I deployed all the files (works on local) again to be sure there was no error in a file. But still there was a 404 error.
When I tried running the Dev database on the live server the site runs perfectly. So I reckon it's a database issue of the live database.

When I tried to use the core_config_data table of the dev database, the shop still doesn't function and returns a 404 error on every request. So I suppose it is not a config error as well. I tried the same with the core_url_rewrite table (lots of relation errors), but still 404 everywhere (frontend + admin).

Another very interesting fact is that the shop is still running from the Chrome browser of my colleague (but only that specific browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not had a default store_view anymore because I renamed it to EN, my colleague had probably a cookie referenced with running the storeview EN.

I added in my nginx host map file the following to fix the issue:

```
map $host $storecode {
  hostnames;
  default en;
}
```